# Android TextView measureText for Arabic

Tags: android, unicode, textview, arabic

Paint.measureText is not accurate with Arabic text. Here is what I tried:

I have a TextView tv1.

`tv1.getWidth();` gives 480, which is okay. `tv1.getPaint().measureText("المؤلف : عبدالرحمن ابن أبي بكر أبو الفضل السيوطي");` gives 502, which is bigger than the screen width.

Bad result, since the text is taking about 80% of the line width! The result should be around 400.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi yZaroui, i too have same kind of issue. please help me, if you have solution for this.

Comment: Me too, have same problem, and the problem appears on Galaxy Tab only! Working fine on Galaxy S3!

Comment: I've faced the same issue, Try to change the font.

Answer (score 0):

i faced this problem today . everything is working as expected and you should know that when your text contains Arabic vowels like `ّ ِ ُ َ`     chars , they are all being calculated in the width as seperate chars and android Paint.measureText is not aware that it shouldnt take those chars into account , because they wont add extra width and they will be drawn on top and bottom of other chars.

the solution is : you should first remove those chars from text and then measure your text.